# I am trying to fetch all those "num" from the given table where the "OUT" > "IN"

Tags: mysql, sql

We can have multiple records for a single "num" value. We need to print the output in ascending order of num.

Table :

```
create table bill
( 
  type varchar(5),
  num varchar(12),
  dur int
);


  insert into bill values
  ('OUT',1818,13),
  ('IN', 1818,10),
  ('OUT',1818,7),
  ('OUT',1817,15),
  ('IN',1817,18),
  ('IN',1819,18),
  ('OUT',1819,40),
  ('IN',1819,18)
```

This is what I am querying : I am grouping the records on "type" in different sub - queries and fetching the records where "OUT" > "IN".

```
select a.num
from 
(select num,sum(dur) as D
 from bill  
 where type ='OUT'
 group by num) a ,

(select num,sum(dur) as D
        from bill  
         where type ='IN'
            group by num) b 
        
where a.D > b.D
group by a.num
order by 1

My output:     Expected output:
num             num
1817           1818
1818           1819
1819
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use condition aggregate function in a subquery and add where `type in ('IN','OUT')` which might get better performance if you created an index on `type` at first column

```
SELECT num
FROM (
    SELECT num,
           SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' THEN dur ELSE 0 END) outval, 
           SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' THEN dur ELSE 0 END) inval
    FROM bill  
    WHERE type in ('IN','OUT')
    GROUP BY num
) t1
WHERE outval > inval
```

[sqlfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c027a7fb67fb5267da7b10cb0711ad42)

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I wanted to know whether it is the usual way we can solve such problems where we have to group the similar values present in same column . Or we can follow other approach also. Can you suggest edits  in my approach.

Comment: @rahulkushwaha why do you care about the approach? Surely the goal is to obtain the correct results?

Comment: Yeah, that's true. Thanks for quick response.

Comment: Hi downvoter. why downvote me? it might be worked at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c027a7fb67fb5267da7b10cb0711ad42

Comment: ^^^ agreed - very odd

Comment: The subquery here is unnecessary and can be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```
SELECT num
FROM bill
GROUP BY num
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'OUT' THEN dur ELSE 0 END) >
       SUM(CASE WHEN type = 'IN' THEN dur ELSE 0 END);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, can we follow other approach different from "CASE" statement.

Comment: @rahulkushwaha whats wrong with a case expression? (its not a statement).

Comment: Nothing wrong, it works perfect.
I was trying to solve it using joins /sub-queries or union, never gave a though about CASE. Thanks for the solution.